# Instalar Certificado SSL manualmente

Tags: certificado-ssl, godaddy, certificado

Tengo mi certificado SSL que me brinda Goddady, intento instalarlo desde el mmc en mi servidor manualmente porque ellos cobran por eso proceso, pero mi página sigue mostrandome el certificado anterior. ¿Alguién lo ha hecho?

Comment: Hola. [Aquí está todo explicado](https://es.godaddy.com/help/instalar-manualmente-un-certificado-ssl-en-mi-hosting-cpanel-12027).

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que no tengo Cpanel, la instalación tiene que ser manualmente ya que es un IIS 10 con win server 2016

Comment: ¿Leíste [esto](https://es.godaddy.com/help/instalar-manualmente-un-certificado-ssl-en-mi-servidor-iis-10-27349)?

Comment: Es correcto, ya lei las indicaciones y segui los pasos, incluso he visto algunos videos pero lamentablemente sigue mostrando el certificado del año pasado